# Rails gems: What are the differences and benefits of SocialStream Vs CommunityEngine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm evaluating the different social gems for Ruby on rails 3.1

SocialStream CommunityEngine seem the leaders in this area.
did anyone compare the two and can share his thoughts?